# ApiError when trying to move Firebase Storage file using Firebase Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am trying to move Firebase Storage file using functions. I am on this for hours but whatever I do, I am getting very strange *ApiError*.

Simplest version of the code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const storageRoot = admin.storage().bucket()

exports.moveFile = (oldPath, newPath) => {
    return storageRoot.file(oldPath).move(newPath)
}
```

The error that this code is causing:

```
ApiError: Not Found
at Object.parseHttpRespBody (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:199:30)
at Object.handleResp (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:137:18)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:502:12
at Request.onResponse [as _callback] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:195:7)
at Request.self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
code: 404,
errors: [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'notFound', message: 'Not Found' } ],
response: undefined,
message: 'Not Found'
```

The admin SDK initialization is presnet in different file and looks like this `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)`. *Any* ideas are *very* wellcomed.

Comment: As discussed elsewhere, please post the entire, minimal code that reproduces the error.  Your code here is missing the init of the admin SDK.

Comment: @DougStevenson Please read my **entire** question. The admin SDK init code is included in the end with a note that the init is in different file.

Comment: It will be easier to diagnose what's going on if you provide an MCVE rather than code fragments.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve